# ¿Por que una función para recorrer un array ejecuta una accion para una palabra parecida a la buscada en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Posee un sistema para recorrer una array revisando si se ha ingresado alguna de las palabras permitidas:

```
<!-- norte, sur, este, oeste -->
```

Asigno el valor a `accionActual` usando un `input.value.`, quedando algo asi:

```
accionActual="norte";

function recorrerArray(accionJugador) {
    for (let i = 0; i < accionesPermitidas.length; i++) {
        if (accionJugador.indexOf(accionesPermitidas[i]) !== -1) {
            accionActual = accionesPermitidas[i];
            informacionJuegoMensaje = "El jugador ha decidido: "+accionActual;
            elegirMapa();
            break;
        } else {
        elegirMapa();
        }
    }
}
```

Luego en base a que palabra fue escrita se hara una accion con un switch.

```
function elegirMapa() {
    switch (accionActual) {
    case "norte":
        posicionJugador -= 3;
        actualizarInformacion();
        actualizarPosicionJugador();
        break;
    case "este":
        posicionJugador -= 1;
        actualizarInformacion();
        actualizarPosicionJugador();
        actualizarImagenesMapa();
        break;
    case "sur":
        posicionJugador += 3;
        actualizarInformacion();
        actualizarPosicionJugador();
        actualizarImagenesMapa();
        break;
    case "oeste":
        posicionJugador += 1;
        actualizarInformacion();
        actualizarPosicionJugador();
        actualizarImagenesMapa();
        break;
    default:
        informacionJuegoMensaje = "No conozco esa accion";
        actualizarInformacion();
        break;
    }
}
```

**El problema:** si escribo "oeste" o "este", se ejecutara la accion de "este".

¿ Como puedo hacer para que valide tambien "oeste", sin que se tome como fuera "este". ?

**NOTA:** *Se que el programa buscara la palabra especificamente, y si meto algo como "quiero ir al norte", encontrara "norte".
Es decir, la primera palabra que se forme sera la que encuentre, porque si "oeste" se forma primero no lo reconoce ?*

Comment: @Rubén lo del "oezte fue la prueba, alli digo que use eso para comprobar, y asigno el valor con un `document.querySelector().value`

Comment: @Rubén corregido

Comment: @Rubén no problem, lag xD

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61906/discussion-between-victor-random-and-ruben).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resulta, que en este caso, el orden de los factores si altera el producto.

Como se busca el array por orden, y la primer palabra que aparece es "este", entonces la intruccion `accionJugador.indexOf(accionesPermitidas[i]) !== -1` siempre va a encontrar la palabra "este", aun cuando lo escrito sea "oeste" porque justamente hace una busqueda secuencial, no por palabras, de las cuatro letras posicionalmente.. es mas, lo que esa pasando es que uno escribe "oeste".. y eso ya contiene "este".

Comment: Si coloco espacios: `" norte "`. no reconoce que se halla escrito norte o cualquier elemento, pero si funciona el ordenar el array

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que una forma más simple, y que te quitaría el problema es usar expresiones regulares para extraer la dirección del texto obtenido mediante el input.

Ejemplo:

Se usa usa la expresión regular `/norte|sur|este|oeste/` para declarar las direcciones válidas, luego se usa `match` para verificar si la cadena incluye una de esas palabras, en caso de que así sea, devuelve una matriz incluyendo la palabra, en caso contrario devuelve `null`.

```js
re = /norte|sur|este|oeste/;

/*Caso de prueba 1 */

str1 = "quiero ir al oeste";
test1 = str1.match(re);
output = Array.isArray(test1)?test1[0]:"Sin dirección";
console.log(output);

/*Caso de prueba 2 */

str2 = "no quiero ir";
test2 = str2.match(re);
output = Array.isArray(test2)?test2[0]:"Sin dirección";
console.log(output);
```